# How do I cascade Styles in a Universal Windows Platform app?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I am yet again struggling with UWP. It seems that I am unable to cascade Styles within Styles. Is this something else that is not allowed in UWP?

This is what I am trying to do...

```
        <Style x:Key="MainMenuRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Backgroud" Value="Grey"/>
            <Style.Resources TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```

However, VS2015 complains that the <Style.Resources> is invalid. I do not want to have to individually style the TextBlock within my RadioButton's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading within styles not supported in UWP (or XAML in general). What you usually do is split up re-usable styles/properties and reference those.

```
<Thickness x:Key="MyMargin">"12,0,0,0"</Thickness>

<Style x:Key="MainMenuRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Grey"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource MyMargin}" />
</Style>
```

What you try to achieve is 'alter' the template of a `RadioButton`. You can find the full template here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299147.aspx. If you dig into the template, you'll see this piece of code:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

This is the part that's showing the actual content of your `RadioButton` and as you can see it's not a `TextBlock`, but a `ContentPresenter` (which will show text as if it was a `TextBlock`). The good news is that this control has a `Margin` property, which takes the value of the `Padding` property from the template. So to achieve what you want, you can simple fill in this property:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Grey"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource MyMargin}" />
</Style>
```

If you want to change properties that are not available in the default template, then you'll have to create your own template.

Comment: Bart, thank you. You opening line confirming it is not possible was what I was expecting, which is a real shame. XAML Styles in WPF do have this ability which is very much like CSS. The more I try to develop within UWP the more frustrated I am becoming. Microsoft's tag line of "A developers' best experience" is a joke. There's no Entity Framework support, no SQL Express, No Merge Replication support using SQL Express. There are controls gone from the toolbox, like StatusBar, DataGrid, DockPanel. My development experience so far is slow and frustrating. Anyway, rant over and thanks again.

Comment: It's still a sandbox environment (rewritten from scratch), so you're limited indeed. Hope you'll learn to live with it at some point (after 3+y I'm used to the sandbox) and start to enjoy it :)

Comment: As frustrating as it is, when I find or develop an alternate solution (Like writing my own data replication) it sure is satisfying. Cheers Bart. :)